# Unity Vector3 Issues

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public class sphere : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool jump;
    Rigidbody rig;
    float horizontalInput;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            jump = true;
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (jump)
        {
            rig.AddForce(Vector3.up * 3, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            jump = false;
        }

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput*3, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Here, when I press play, whenever my ball jumps, it jumps very slowly, as if something is trying to oppose it. Also when it comes down, it comes down way too slow.

Can anyone explain what's happening here and suggest a solution for it.

Comment: Can you post more code? This snippet is setting your x velocity to `horizontalInput` and the rest to 0. There is no vertical movement, so no jumping...

Answer (score 0):

You can use for Gameobject Jumping best way
And please check your Mass and Gravity Value

```
private Rigidbody rb;
public float power = 5;

private void Start
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Jump
{
    rb.AddForce(0f, power, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to properly understand this: horizontalInput is a variable with a minimum value of -1 and a maximum value of +1. It is not used to set the "speed" or the "force" but merely the direction.

Now then, and I am speculating here since you haven't provided enough code, you are setting directly the velocity. This is fine if this is what you want to do, however you must be aware that you are you are going around the physics system. Are you sure you want that? If you are, you must do something like this:

```
public float jumpForce; // Set this at the inspector

...

GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput * jumpForce, 0, 0);
```

Now, about the fall... The RigidBody component makes your object behave in a certain way, that obeys the laws of physics. Your object will reach a certain height, at wich its speed will be 0 before dropping down accelerating according to the objects mass.

That means that it will fall slowly at first while moving faster at a constant rate.

If you want it to fall faster, you need to change the mass value at the object's RigidBody component.

That being said, it is weird to use physics for only half of the movement. It can work and has worked with great success (i.e.: Flappy Bird), but it is fundamentally wrong.

Edit: Typo

Comment: I've uploaded the full code. Some guy said that as I press jump, the Y position is changing but the velocity component has Y=0, so that velocity is making that y =0. It's like both the jump function and velocity(y=0) are conciding.

Comment: The guy made the following correction :    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput*3, GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y, 0);                                       Here what  is the meaning of the line he replaced instead of 0?